# how i can modify the style block comment in sublime text

Tags: php, sublimetext2, sublimetext

the form of comment block for php in sublime-text looks like this.

```
/ * Example * /
```

I would like to change it to look like that.

```
/** 
* example 
**/
```

I try to modify the file in Comments.tmPreferences Package / php / but I'm not coming. I do not understand the xml use. 
I know it is not much, but just personal choice.

Comment: DockBlock may help --- https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/DocBlockr

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [sublime-jsdocs](https://github.com/spadgos/sublime-jsdocs)

install the package, and you should be able to make docblock comments.
By Pressing enter or tab after /** (or ###* for Coffee-Script) will yield a new line and will close the comment.

With Package Control installed, you can install DocBlockr from inside Sublime Text itself. Open the Command Palette and select "Package Control: Install Package", then search for DocBlockr and you're done!

you can do this:

[image] (Docblock completion)

[image] (Comment extension)

or this:

[image]